# Finding an "inverse function" symmetrical to y=2x not y=x

Tags: functions, inverse

Hello I'm very inexperienced in math (I know a little about derivation/integrals etc but nothing on university level) so my terminology will not be on point (as well due to english not being my native language). I have a function

$$
y=\sqrt2*\sqrt x  
$$
[graph 1 and 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVtF8.png)
[image]

and I want to find the symmetrical function by the function $y=2x$
like this:

[in previous file on the right]

as far as I know the inverse function is always symmetrical by the function $y=x$. so I dont know how to call this. Expected result:

[graph 3 and 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irloe.png)
[image]
I'm doing this because I wanna to "connect" these function so I can "draw" this

[in previous file on the right]

I can only post 2 links so I have combined graph 1 and 2 into one image and 3 and 4 into another one. Thank you in advance for responding! <3

Comment: Your "symmetrical function" is not a function: there exists an $x$ with two different $y$ values.  You could write it as a set of parametric equations.

Comment: yeah I know its not a function by definition but i dont know how to easily call it. Sure but I'm asking you/anyone how to figure those parametric equations

Comment: yeah thats what i tried but it looks like [this](http://i.imgur.com/xIzeN1m.png). my question was probably incorrect to what im trying to accomplish

Comment: I'm going back to my answer of "use parametric equations".  I don't have a full description ready of how to do that yet.  Maybe in about 3 hours I'll have time to put that together for you.

Comment: ok thank you. im looking forward to your answer

Comment: I managed to get a non-parametric form, but I don't think it can be written in a $y=f(x)$ form.  Let me know if it helps or if there is more information you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

The reflection in a line $y=x\tan \theta$ is represented by the matrix

\begin{pmatrix}
\cos 2\theta & \sin 2\theta \\
\sin 2\theta & -\cos 2\theta
\end{pmatrix}

In your case $\tan \theta =2$. Now using so called t-substitution, letting $t=\tan\theta$ we have

$$
\cos 2\theta = \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2} \; \; \text{and} \;\; \sin 2\theta = \frac{2t}{1+t^2}
$$

So the matrix is

\begin{pmatrix}
-3/5 & 4/5 \\
4/5 & 3/5
\end{pmatrix}

Hence position vector of reflected points are

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
-3/5 & 4/5 \\
4/5 & 3/5
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
\sqrt{2x}
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
-\frac{3}{5}x + \frac{4}{5} \sqrt{2x}\\
\frac{4}{5} x + \frac{3}{5} \sqrt{2x}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

The plot of this on Wolfram alpha shows that it is not a function:
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%28x%2Cy%29%3D+%28-3t%2F5+%2B4sqrt%282t%29+%2F5%2C+4t%2F5+%2B3sqrt%282t%29+%2F5%29

Edit: Also this parametric curve interset $y=\sqrt{2x}$ at two different points, also computed by Wolfram alpha - http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%28x%2Cy%29%3D+%28-3t%2F5+%2B4sqrt%282t%29+%2F5%2C+4t%2F5+%2B3sqrt%282t%29+%2F5%29

So the part of graph which you want is parameterized by paramters lying between these two solutions.

Comment: okay thank you very much. i have close to zero knowledge what a matrix is and how it works but  from what I've deduced. i have [this curve](http://i.imgur.com/f4U1OQ6.png) but it is not a function. so I cannot calculate y just with x? so I cannot write y = (something something including x). correct?

Comment: @honzaik The fact that the curve does not represent a function doesn't mean it cannot be expressed in a form $y=f(x)$ (for instance $x^2+y^2=1$ is a circle, and you may represent this by $y=\pm \sqrt{1-x^2}$). However in this case I cannot see any sensible way to transform parametric form into a standard form (something that can be expressed as $f(x,y)=0$). Probably some sophiscated technique can be applied to find such form, since the plotted curve seems to be parabolic.  But unfortunately I don't see any way to do so.

Comment: i see. i certainly didnt think this would be that complicated, so I will probably find another way. I learned a lot! thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is actually quite a trivial way to do this. So as you know the inverse swaps the $x$ and $y$ values and is therefore symmetric to the line $y=x$, and note we get the inverse by plugging in $y$ for $x$ and vise versa.
Now if we want to make it symmetric to the line $y=2x$, we just have to exchange all the $y$s for $2x$, and all the $2x$s for $y$. So we have
$$y=\sqrt{2x} \Rightarrow 2x=\sqrt{y}$$
or
$$y=4x^2, x\ge 0$$
Note: We constrict the domain because in the original function, defined implicitly by $2x=\sqrt{y}$, $2x$ must be greater than $0$ for there to ever be a corresponding $y$ value. And if you graph it it will make even more sense.

Comment: (see my comment on the question)

Comment: Graph this, there is no need for parametric equations. Your original comment is incorrect. @abiessu

Comment: I believe the OP has already provided graph #3, or is there a mistaken procedure there that causes it to only look like there's a problem?

Comment: Your math makes sense; I'm only trying to square it with the picture shown in the question.

Comment: @abiessu , maybe I am wrong, I just thought he wanted to see how to find that function. But after reading it, is he looking for a function that "combines" these two?

Comment: I'm not concerned about graph #4, that would just be a piece-wise fit of whatever functions are desired.

Comment: thanks! I knew it would be trivial. I have not really thought about it that way, its pretty clear now. ty! but I have tried it and [this](http://i.imgur.com/9zYViTH.png)  does not look perfectly symmetrical tho. when I zoom in on the 0-1 area [too](http://i.imgur.com/gBz3bE7.png). so if I modify it as 4(x-0.5)^2 + 1 so I can reposition it so it "connects" it looks like [this](http://i.imgur.com/xIzeN1m.png) maybe I cannot just do this but I dont see it being symmetrical at least according to those 2 images.

Comment: Im not really looking for function that combines these two (maybe Im in theory). I have already the sqrt(2x) function where x is (0 to 0.5) and I wanna find another function that looks like that one (in the graph 4) in the area (0.5 and 1).

Comment: The math makes sense, but it doesn't provide the symmetry that the OP is looking for.  That would only be achieved by parametric equations.

Comment: I see. when you rotate it 180 degress it ["fits"](http://i.imgur.com/NL25ks2.png)

Comment: This is so weird because the grapher says that the two functions don't intersect $y=2x$ at the same point, but if you solve for the intersects by hand they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

In order to reflect about this line, we should put this equation in the context of the line:

$$y = \sqrt{2x} \to y^2-2x=0\\
y = 2x\to y-2x=0$$

Line $u$ would be the axis of reflection, for $y-2x = 0$, line $v$ would be the perpendicular, with $2y+x = 0$.  In terms of $u$ and $v$, we have

$$\left(\frac 15u+\frac25v\right)^2-2\left(\frac15v-\frac25u\right)=y^2-2x$$

Now a reflection about the line $v$ is simply a matter of negating $u$, giving us

$$\left(\frac 15u-\frac25v\right)^2-\frac25v-\frac45u=\left(\frac35y+\frac45x\right)^2-\frac85y+\frac65x$$

This can be algebraically expanded further as desired.

[image: Desmos graph of the two functions]

By comparison, here is the graph of the suggested function $y=4x^2$ vs. $y^2=2x$:

[image: non-mirror graph]

(Graph testing done using https://www.desmos.com/calculator.)